# When I run the make command on my project directory in Linux, I get the following error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

cannot create regular file. Text file busy
make: *** [install-bin] Error 1

I am running the make command from the project folder.

I am creating an executable for my cpp file. Can someone please help me? I am very new to linux.

Comment: It sounds like you're getting a "file in use" error.  What file is causing the problem?  In all likelihood, you're still *executing* the program you're trying to *build*.  SUGGESTION: use `ps -eaf` and `kill -9` to see if you're executing the program before "make", and terminate it.

Comment: @paulsm4 I states that it cannot create the regular file in the directory of the cpp file.

Comment: Dude - you haven't told us either a) *which* file is "busy", or b) exactly *where* that file is located.  I'll bet that the file is the same executable you're trying to build.  Useful commands: [ps -eaf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps), [kill -9](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) and [lsof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof).  PS: please update your post with any additional info you can provide (e.g. from "lsof", or the "make" output).

Comment: @paulsm4 I realized on how to solve the issue. I just deleted the build folder and the exe file and remade the Make file and the issue seems to get solved.

Comment: @ollc I realized on how to solve the issue. I just deleted the build folder and the exe file and remade the Make file and the issue seems to get solved.

Answer (score 1):

`EBUSY` occurs when you try to `open` a file that is currently being executed. Instead, you should `unlink` the file first, and then `creat` it.

If you're using the shell, make sure you use `install` rather than `cp`.

Comment: @ollc may you please clarify what do you mean by unlink the first one and then create it. I had created the exe using the make command initially but then I make some changes in the code and decided to redo the make command. When I do the make, it gives me this error.

Comment: I am not installing any file, I am just creating an executable for the cpp file.

Comment: Apparently you are running the executable from the place it is built, rather than installing it (at least into `${DESTDIR}`). You *can* use `rm -f $@` at the start of your make rule, but you really should fix your execution workflow.